# Image WPF not showing at runtime, after moved MainWindow.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my application I have moved

- `MainWindow.xaml`
- `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

to folder `app` in my project(of course I have changed  in my `App.xaml` `StartupUri="app/MainWindow.xaml"`).

After that my Image isn't showing the picture at runtime.:

```
<Image Source="asd.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="170"  Width="201"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also change the source of image to `Source="/WpfApplication;component/asd.jpg"`:

```
<Image Source="/WpfApplication;component/asd.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       Height="170"  Width="201"/>
```

`WpfApplication` is the name of your application.